# What is this plant? Is it a lavender, russian sage, or something else?

Tags: identification, lavender

I had 4 plants near my front door. One of them died and I was trying to replace it. I bought a lavender from Home Depot and it was totally different as you can see (the small one in the middle of my larger ones (around 2 feet high 3 feet wide)). Can you help me identify what my plant is? What type? Where to buy it from? Any other suggestions (alternatives that will be about similar size and looks nice with mine)? Thank you in advance. I live in Phoenix (can get real hot) and this will receive the afternoon sun.

[image: Picture of my plant]

Answer (score 6):

Looks to be some cultivar of *Lavandula multifida*, the fernleaf lavender. I could take a punt at a cultivar name and suggest 'Spanish Eyes'  as it is probably the most common cultivar, but to be honest without it sitting in front of me, next to a known specimen of 'Spanish Eyes' I couldn't confirm that.

They are not the hardiest of species, but that shouldn't be too much of an issue in Phoenix, just makes sure that it never gets soggy feet. Like all lavenders, they like good drainage. Good pairings would be similar mediterranean species.
In general, if a plant is growing well, then look to plants that would grow alongside it in the wild for other plants that are likely to be successful. I would suggest *Rosmarinus officinalis* if you need a bit of height (possibly in the corner). Other culinary herbs - *Salvia*, *Origanum* and *Thymus* might be nice. *Phlomis sp.* would look good. You could put some grasses in for contrast *Stipa gigantea* as alternative for the back and perhaps *Nassella tenuissima* for mid- to foreground planting. You don't want too many similar shrubs sitting next to each other or it's going to get a bit dull.

UPDATE:
@stormy rightly mentioned in a comment that too many different types of plant will look chaotic. The list of plants above was to give a range of options that you may wish to choose one or two from - not all of them!

Given you want a quick fix, you could opt for another more readily available *Lavandula*. I would pick one that is sufficiently different not to look mismatched. If you pick another blue/pale lilac coloured one it look like you've tried to match it and failed. One with white flowers is probably your safest bet - *Lavandula x intermedia 'Alba'*. It will get a bit bigger than yours but should fill the gaps nice and quick. This is one of the more common white lavenders (or lavandins in this case) and also one of the tougher varieties - I'd be surprised if you couldn't find plants locally.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. I think the easiest for me is to find the same and plant it. I'm illiterate in gardening and deciding/ finding an alternative is likely to be difficult for me. Do you know where to find that Lavandula multifida 'Spanish Eyes'? When I searched I found seeds but did not find the plant itself. I prefer to buy it and plant it instead of growing seeds. Thank you.

Comment: I'm based in the UK so I can't help with nursery suggestions. In the UK the RHS have a plant finder app that finds UK) suppliers for plants. Perhaps something similar exists in the US. *Lavandula* are relatively easy from seed but if you need an instant fix, perhaps using another species/cultivar would work. See update to answer.

Answer (score -1):

Artemesia 'Powis Castle'...these grey plants go with anything. I am not sure about the ID at all. Let's ID this guy for sure and I would buy more to make a soft informal edge in this spot. You could add a few Crocosmia, Lucifer or the yellow Crocosmia?  [Crocosmia pictures](https://images.search.yahoo.com/yhs/search;_ylt=A86.Jyi1XBNZ.GIA3HAnnIlQ;_ylu=X3oDMTByNWU4cGh1BGNvbG8DZ3ExBHBvcwMxBHZ0aWQDBHNlYwNzYw--?p=Crocosmia&fr=yhs-mozilla-002&hspart=mozilla&hsimp=yhs-002)

Comment: Not with flowers like that it isn't. 'Powis Castle' is also noticeably more silver.

Comment: I like your suggestions especially the additions.  The word for too many types of plants is CHAOTIC the opposite of DULL.  Grins.  I'll go check your choices for ID as well.  Oh, and the coloring can change drastically with the environment.  I love these gray plants, senecio all except gag me Dusty Miller.

Comment: You seem to be totally correct with Lavandula multifida!  Whoa!  I agree.  Not ottoclast or spanish lavender...good ID George!